# Where is git installed with cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, egit

I am going through the EGit user guide and it says I should point out the system wide configuration by telling Eclipse where Git is installed with Windows and then it says I should do the same if I am using Cygwin.  I'm not sure where in my Cygwin folder Git is installed.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks!

Comment: When I tried it I got /usr/bin/git which I assume /usr is the equivalent to {{cygwin_path}} in the answer below.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can point to  {{cygwin_path}}/bin/git.exe
or you can install git separately and point to that instance.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know where it was but I found it with your help.